# In Django forms, logical validation for the field

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-modal

I've three fields in my model phone number, email & password.

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
    max_length=17, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)`
```

[user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLe9o.png)
 In forms, I'm using two fields phone_number & password[forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sln04.png) 
    class Userloginform(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = AppUser
    fields = ['phone_number', 'password']
```

I write functionality for user able to login using phone number and email also. [login functionalities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9zDx.png)

```
def login_app_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Userloginform(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['phone_number']
        password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = AppUser.objects.get(Q(email__iexact=username) | (Q(phone_number__iexact=username)), is_active=True)
            if user and check_password(password, user.password):
                request.session['username'] = user.phone_number
                # return HttpResponse('success')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/homepage', {'username': user.phone_number})
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Credientials')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, 'user doesnot exists')
    else:
        login_form = Userloginform()
    return render(request, 'navbar.html', {'form2':login_form})
```

Its working fine. 
In Front end, I'm using Bootstrap Modal form pop up. it also working fine. Problem is my error message. If wrong password, [wrong password for phone number field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms6Ux.png)it will pop up show error message in form itself, this is working. When I give doesn't exists, here I'm facing issue. when I give email ID,[email field doesn't exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsryL.png) its pop up but when I use phone number its not coming. I don't know, where I made mistake

Comment: While this does not answer your problem, I suggest having a generic error message "Invalid credentials". You don't want people to know that _"the email DOES have an account, so maybe you could bruteforce its password"_. Whether the password OR the email/phone is wrong, always answer "Wrong credentials".

Comment: What happens when you submit with an incorrect phone number? Nothing? No error message whatsoever?

Comment: @JordanKowal, using email/phone wrong password its okay, If email/phone isn't registered, if i need to display this?

Comment: Do not link to images of your code. Use the question editor to copy and format your code inline inside the question. No one wants to open your links one by one and try to read the code in images. Please read [ask].

Comment: @dirkgroten, i understand that. Now I need the solution.

Comment: Then edit your question and show us your code.

Comment: @dirkgroten, please check it now. But in front end, i'm getting error, that i shared as. link

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what’s going wrong and what happens: there’s just one field for username. If you just enter something like “blabla” it doesn’t show an error? Give us examples in which it gives an error and in which case not. And what is expected/unexpected behavior. When you say “it’s not coming” what do you mean? is that the issue?

Comment: @dirkgroten, there's just one field for username. Using mobile or email, user can login. In Form, I'm using Phone number field
Case 1 - correct (mobile or email) - enter correct password :- working
Case 2 - correct (mobile or email) , enter wrong password :- working
Case 3 - wrong(email - not in DB), entered password :- working (POP UP message showing)
Case 4 - wrong(mobile - not in DB), entered password :- working. (but POP Up not coming)

Comment: I don't understand the difference between case 3 and case 4. In both cases you enter a string in the same field that doesn't correspond to either an email nor a mobile. So what is the string exactly?

Comment: @dirkgroten, I too don't know but my guess is due to form it's not showing. Because I'm using phone number field

Comment: But what is the exact input in both cases? Just tell us the actual strings you try.

Comment: for email - abc@abc.com and mobile - 1234567890. These error its not because of input. Its because of forms only